# Creating what is equivalent to an ISAPI extension for IIS7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've searched the IIS7 MSDN database but can't find any *concrete* material on how to create custom C#.NET extensions for IIS7, I know that previously in IIS6 you had to write an ISAPI extension in C++ if you wanted to say plug in your own scripting language for websites (this is sort of what I want to do) but in IIS7 you're supposed to be able to write it using C#.NET and utilizing the new plugable architecture of IIS7... but I can't find any sodding docs on how to do it.

Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good place to start is this [article](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/08/15/Developing-IIS7-web-server-features-with-the-.NET-framework.aspx). It has links in the beginning to sample modules.

Answer (score 4):

In IIS7 Integrated mode, HTTP Modules are equivalent to ISAPI filters and HTTP Handlers are equivalent to ISAPI extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HTTP handlers](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, still use the ISAPI C++ interfaces.  There may be existing code you can use to enable your new scripting language, since the C++ stuff has been around for sooooo much longer.